# How to join two relations in pig with multiple fields

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hortonworks-sandbox

I've two CSV files:

1- Fertiltiy.csv :

[image]

2- Life Expectency.csv :

[image]

I want to join them in pig so that the result will be like this:

[image]

I am new to pig, I couldn't get the correct answer, but here is my code:

```
fertility = LOAD 'fertility' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();

lifeExpectency = LOAD 'lifeExpectency' USING   org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();

A = JOIN fertility by country, lifeExpectency by country; 

B = JOIN fertility by year, lifeExpectency by year; 

C = UNION A,B;

DUMP C;
```

Here is the result of my code:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the join by country and year and select the necessary columns needed for your final output.

```
fertility = LOAD 'fertility' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
lifeExpectency = LOAD 'lifeExpectency' USING   org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();

A = JOIN fertility by (country,year), lifeExpectency by (country,year); 
B = FOREACH A GENERATE  fertility::country,fertility::year,fertility::fertility,lifeExpectency::lifeExpectency;  
DUMP B;
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked. 
Just replace DUMP C with DUMP B so I can accept it as a correct answer.

Comment: @AliZuhair Updated. Thanks in advance for accepting.